# can't find variable :useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

So I get this error after I fetched data and tried to assign it to my const. I'm using hooks for the first time and I don't know what I did wrong. here is my code:

```
export default function MedProfilScreen({route}){
    //const {id,name,specialite,work}=route.params;
    const [data,setData]=useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
      fetch('http:......)
    
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setData(data.res);
    console.log(res)
   })
    .done();
    });
```

And this is what the console.log shows:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "code": "12459552",
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Dr xavier vilan",
    "speciality": "Cardio",
  },
  Object {
    "education": Array [
      Object {
        "date_debut": "2020-02-07",
        "date_end": "2020-02-06",
        "diplome": "asmaa",
        "school": "asmaa",
        "city": "vullez",
      },
      ]}
]
```

Comment: have you imported useState ?

Comment: import `useState` like `import { useState } from 'react';`

Comment: thank you i didn't import {useState} it fixed it for me

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add

```
import {useState} from "react";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import `useState` from `React`, or use `React.useState` (if you imported `'react'` as `React`).
Also, you must provide the `setData` to `useEffect`, or it will render a warning.

```
useEffect(() => {your function}, [setData])
```

Comment: one more thing please, what's the equivalent to "this.setState({data:res }) in my code?"

Comment: Hi @Aymen, the equivalent will be .. setData(res) , assuming the value that you want to store in the data state is res.